# Can't parse date with zone information using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: timezone, simpledateformat

I have

format: `dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:sszzz`

locale: `en_US`

date: `01-02-2016T10:00:00+01:00`

zoneId: `Europe/Warsaw`

and I call:

`new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale).parse(date).toInstant().atZone(zoneId)`

and I get `Unparseable date: "01-02-2016T10:00:00+01:00"`

Is there any option to use SimpleDateFormat or do I need to change it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `"01-02-2016T10:00:00+01:00"`, your format string should be `"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"`.  You have `zzz` where you should have `XXX`.  See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Also, this is quite a strange format to use.  Usually, when one sees the `T` separator between date and time parts, it indicates the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (or an ISO8601-based format such as [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)).  However, in that format, the date is in year-month-day order.  You have day-month-year order.  This contradiction will surely cause confusion at some point.  I highly recommend changing the source of this data to either use the correct ordering, or replace the `T` with a space, and place a space before the tz offset as well.

In other words, your data should look like:

```
"01-02-2016 10:00:00 +01:00"  // Human-readable, but locale-specfic
```

or

```
"2016-02-01T10:00:00+01:00"   // ISO8601 / RFC3339 compliant
```

NOT

```
"01-02-2016T10:00:00+01:00"   // Nonsense
```